# PHP Registeration doesn't insert user into database after successful registeration

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out what is exactly causing the problem. First I'm using panique php-login-advanced. The problem is that whenever a user registers successfully they don't get inserted into the database. I'm currently using wamp /w phpmyadmin. I disabled the whole mailing system before hand to see if the users get added tot he database but they don't. I'm assuming I might have messed up the query. But if I did I  would  have gotten an error.

I get no errors. When registeration is successful

```
class Registration
{
    /**
     * @var object $db_connection The database connection
     */
    private $db_connection            = null;
    /**
     * @var bool success state of registration
     */
    public  $registration_successful  = false;
    /**
     * @var bool success state of verification
     */
    public  $verification_successful  = false;
    /**
     * @var array collection of error messages
     */
    public  $errors                   = array();
    /**
     * @var array collection of success / neutral messages
     */
    public  $messages                 = array();


    /**
     * the function "__construct()" automatically starts whenever an object of this class is created,
     * you know, when you do "$login = new Login();"
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        session_start();

        // if we have such a POST request, call the registerNewUser() method
        if (isset($_POST["register"])) {
            $this->registerNewUser($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_email'], $_POST['user_password_new'], $_POST['user_password_repeat'], $_POST['user_safecode'],$_POST["captcha"]);
        // if we have such a GET request, call the verifyNewUser() method
        } else if (isset($_GET["id"]) && isset($_GET["verification_code"])) {
            $this->verifyNewUser($_GET["id"], $_GET["verification_code"]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if database connection is opened and open it if not
     */
    private function databaseConnection()
    {
        // connection already opened
        if ($this->db_connection != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // create a database connection, using the constants from config/config.php
            try {
                // Generate a database connection, using the PDO connector
                // @see http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/
                // Also important: We include the charset, as leaving it out seems to be a security issue:
                // @see http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Connecting_to_MySQL says:
                // "Adding the charset to the DSN is very important for security reasons,
                // most examples you'll see around leave it out. MAKE SURE TO INCLUDE THE CHARSET!"
                $this->db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                return true;
            // If an error is catched, database connection failed
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_DATABASE_ERROR;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * handles the entire registration process. checks all error possibilities, and creates a new user in the database if
     * everything is fine
     */
    private function registerNewUser($user_name, $user_email, $user_password, $user_password_repeat, $user_safecode, $captcha)
    {
        // we just remove extra space on username and email
        $user_name  = trim($user_name);
        $user_email = trim($user_email);

        // check provided data validity
        // TODO: check for "return true" case early, so put this first
        if (strtolower($captcha) != strtolower($_SESSION['captcha'])) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_CAPTCHA_WRONG;
        } elseif (empty($user_name)) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERNAME_EMPTY;
        } elseif (empty($user_password) || empty($user_password_repeat)) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_PASSWORD_EMPTY;
        } elseif ($user_password !== $user_password_repeat) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_PASSWORD_BAD_CONFIRM;
        } elseif (strlen($user_password) < 6) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_PASSWORD_TOO_SHORT;
        } elseif (strlen($user_name) > 64 || strlen($user_name) < 2) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERNAME_BAD_LENGTH;
        } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i', $user_name)) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERNAME_INVALID;
        } elseif (empty($user_email)) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_EMAIL_EMPTY;
        } elseif (strlen($user_email) > 64) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_EMAIL_TOO_LONG;
        } elseif (!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_EMAIL_INVALID;
        } elseif (empty($user_safecode)) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_SAFECODE_EMPTY;
        } elseif (strlen($user_safecode) < 12) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_SAFECODE_BAD_LENGTH;
        } elseif (strlen($user_safecode) > 64) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_SAFECODE_BAD_LENGTH;


        // finally if all the above checks are ok
        } else if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
            // check if username or email already exists
            $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT user_name, user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:user_name OR user_email=:user_email');
            $query_check_user_name->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_check_user_name->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_check_user_name->execute();
            $result = $query_check_user_name->fetchAll();

            // if username or/and email find in the database
            // TODO: this is really awful!
            if (count($result) > 0) {
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
                    $this->errors[] = ($result[$i]['user_name'] == $user_name) ? MESSAGE_USERNAME_EXISTS : MESSAGE_EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS;
                }
            } else {
                // check if we have a constant HASH_COST_FACTOR defined (in config/hashing.php),
                // if so: put the value into $hash_cost_factor, if not, make $hash_cost_factor = null
                $hash_cost_factor = (defined('HASH_COST_FACTOR') ? HASH_COST_FACTOR : null);

                // crypt the user's password with the PHP 5.5's password_hash() function, results in a 60 character hash string
                // the PASSWORD_DEFAULT constant is defined by the PHP 5.5, or if you are using PHP 5.3/5.4, by the password hashing
                // compatibility library. the third parameter looks a little bit shitty, but that's how those PHP 5.5 functions
                // want the parameter: as an array with, currently only used with 'cost' => XX.
                $user_password_hash = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost' => $hash_cost_factor));
                // generate random hash for email verification (40 char string)
                $user_activation_hash = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

                // write new users data into database
                $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime, user_accountstatus, user_group, user_safecode, user_mainaccount) VALUES(:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now(), :user_accountstatus, :user_group, :user_safecode, :user_mainaccount)');
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_password_hash', $user_password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_activation_hash', $user_activation_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_registration_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_accountstatus', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_group', 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_safecode', $user_safecode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_mainaccount', "NULL", PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query_new_user_insert->execute(); // Seems like this doesn't execute

                // id of new user
                $user_id = $this->db_connection->lastInsertId();

                if ($query_new_user_insert) {
                    $send_mail  = true; //bypass mailing system first
                    // send a verification email  $this->sendVerificationEmail($user_id, $user_email, $user_activation_hash)
                    if ($send_mail) { 
                        // when mail has been send successfully
                        $this->messages[] = MESSAGE_VERIFICATION_MAIL_SENT;
                        $this->registration_successful = true;
                    } else {
                        // delete this users account immediately, as we could not send a verification email
                        $query_delete_user = $this->db_connection->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id');
                        $query_delete_user->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $query_delete_user->execute();

                        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_VERIFICATION_MAIL_ERROR;
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_REGISTRATION_FAILED;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * sends an email to the provided email address
     * @return boolean gives back true if mail has been sent, gives back false if no mail could been sent
     */
    public function sendVerificationEmail($user_id, $user_email, $user_activation_hash)
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        // please look into the config/config.php for much more info on how to use this!
        // use SMTP or use mail()
        if (EMAIL_USE_SMTP) {
            // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            //useful for debugging, shows full SMTP errors
            //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
            // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPAuth = EMAIL_SMTP_AUTH;
            // Enable encryption, usually SSL/TLS
            if (defined(EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION)) {
                $mail->SMTPSecure = EMAIL_SMTP_ENCRYPTION;
            }
            // Specify host server
            $mail->Host = EMAIL_SMTP_HOST;
            $mail->Username = EMAIL_SMTP_USERNAME;
            $mail->Password = EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD;
            $mail->Port = EMAIL_SMTP_PORT;
        } else {
            $mail->IsMail();
        }

        $mail->From = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_FROM;
        $mail->FromName = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_FROM_NAME;
        $mail->AddAddress($user_email);
        $mail->Subject = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_SUBJECT;

        $link = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_URL.'?id='.urlencode($user_id).'&verification_code='.urlencode($user_activation_hash);

        // the link to your register.php, please set this value in config/email_verification.php
        $mail->Body = EMAIL_VERIFICATION_CONTENT.' '.$link;

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_VERIFICATION_MAIL_NOT_SENT . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * checks the id/verification code combination and set the user's activation status to true (=1) in the database
     */
    public function verifyNewUser($user_id, $user_activation_hash)
    {
        // if database connection opened
        if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
            // try to update user with specified information
            $query_update_user = $this->db_connection->prepare('UPDATE users SET user_active = 1, user_activation_hash = NULL WHERE user_id = :user_id AND user_activation_hash = :user_activation_hash');
            $query_update_user->bindValue(':user_id', intval(trim($user_id)), PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query_update_user->bindValue(':user_activation_hash', $user_activation_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_update_user->execute();

            if ($query_update_user->rowCount() > 0) {
                $this->verification_successful = true;
                $this->messages[] = MESSAGE_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATION_SUCCESSFUL;
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_REGISTRATION_ACTIVATION_NOT_SUCCESSFUL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shall i re write your Code some what optimized??

Comment: Just a few small comments - you might not want to use session_start() in your class constructor. That kind of thing should probably be in a header somewhere prior to any actual code logic is applied. That way if your Login is ever instantiated multiple times or if it's instantiated after some content is sent, you won't end up with warnings or errors. I'd also suggest moving the GET/POST logic out of the constructor. Let the calling code be the one to tell the Login class that it wants to check for registration and what not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` to see errors. Default behavior is only setting attributes that could be checked "manually" (`PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`).

```
$options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];
$this->db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
```

Comment: Found exactly what I needed to fix apparently I was missing a column.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are using Huge Bindvalue,but execute is working but you can optimize It by simply ex:

```
$stmt->execute(array(
                                 ':user_name' => $user_name,
                                 ':user_password_hash' => $user_password_hash
                                 ));

//add the user ID primary field you are missing that Ajmal PraveeN :)
$user_id = $this->db_connection->lastInsertId('uniqueidfield');
```

and Why you are missing a Unique ID Field..